# Is it possible to explicitly express a simple coherence calculation in terms of linear regression?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, coherence

I'm a mathematician seeking to improve my conceptual understanding of what the coherence between two signals, $x$ and $y$, represents. I know it's analogous to a linear regression coefficient, in that it's calculated by computing the magnitude-squared of the cross-spectral density, $P_{xy}$ and dividing the result by the product of the spectral densities, $P_{xx}$ and $P_{yy}$. (Similar to dividing the covariance by the product of the variances.) It measures the strength of linear association between two signals as a function of frequency, but I'm wondering if there's also a way to think of it explicitly in terms of linear regression for my simple example below.

To be more specific, suppose $f_0=300$ Hz, $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0 g_1(t))$ and $y(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0 g_2(t))$, where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are functions of a single variable. If we sample from $x$ and $y$, is it possible to assess the level of coherence by looking at the correlation coefficient from the sampled values of $g_1$ and $g_2$?

In my example, $f_s=1000$ and I sample for one second. I set $g_1(t)=t$ and add a little noise to each sampled value of $g_1(t)$ to obtain $g_2(t)$. I computed the correlation between the samples of $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$, which equaled .9881. The graphs show the power spectral densities, cross power spectral density magnitude, and coherence.The maximum coherence of .99975 is attained at frequency 300. (Apologies that the code appears after the graphs.)

I repeated the process by changing $g_1(t)$ and/or $g_2(t)$:

1. $g_1(t)=t$ and $g_2(t)=t^{1.001}$. Correlation coefficient= .872; maximum coherence of .98829 at $f=300$.
2. $g_1(t)=t^2$ with noise added, similar to the first example, to get $g_2(t)$. Correlation coefficient=.9882 and maximum coherence of .99611 at $f=247$.

I realize that this question is somewhat vague, but will a larger correlation coefficient between the sampled $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$ correspond to a higher coherence value between the two signals? If so, is there an equation that relates the two?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import coherence, periodogram, csd,
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0, 1, dt)
N=len(t)
fs=1/dt

noise=np.random.uniform(low=-.0001375, high=.0001375, size=(N,))

f0=300

g1=t
g2=t+noise

x = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * g1) 
y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * g2)

corr_coeff=pearsonr(x, y)[0]
print('Correlation Coefficient: '+str(corr_coeff))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4)

f,Pxx=periodogram(x,fs,nfft=len(x)) # 2/(N*fs)
f,Pyy=periodogram(y,fs,nfft=len(y))
f, Pxy = csd(x, y, fs,nfft=len(x))

ax[0].plot(f,Pxx)
ax[0].set_xlabel('frequency')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Pxx')
ax[0].grid(True)

ax[1].plot(f,Pyy)
ax[1].set_xlabel('frequency')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Pyy')
ax[1].grid(True)

ax[2].plot(f,abs(Pxy))
ax[2].set_xlabel('frequency')
ax[2].set_ylabel('|Pxy|')
ax[2].grid(True)

f,Coh=coherence(x,y,fs=fs,nfft=len(x))

f_max=np.argmax(Coh,axis=0)
print('Maximum Coherence of '+str(max(Coh))+' at '+str(f_max))

ax[3].plot(f,Coh)
ax[3].set_xlabel('frequency')
ax[3].set_ylabel('coherence')
ax[3].set_ylim(0, 1.2)
ax[3].grid(True)

plt.show()
```